# Java SQLException: Result Set closed issue

Tags: java, mysql, exception

I have this java function that runs and produces an error.  I cannot figure out why this is occurring because this is the first function in the program to run so no other connections, statements, or result sets have been opened. The error is

```
Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:768)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:7008)
        at equipmentinventoryimporter.Importer.sqlTable(Importer.java:219)
        at equipmentinventoryimporter.Importer.main(Importer.java:58)
```

and the function is

```
private static void sqlTable(SQLTableJob sqltableJob) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection connMySQL2 = null;
            Statement stntMySQL2 = null;
            try {
                connMySQL2 = DriverManager.getConnection(mysqlAddress, mysqlUsername, mysqlPassword);
                stntMySQL2 = connMySQL2.createStatement();
                //MySQL Transaction
                System.out.println("Starting " + sqltableJob.getMysqlTable() + " transaction");
                stntMySQL2.execute("START TRANSACTION");
                String insertQuery = "";
                try {
                    final String inactiveQuery = "UPDATE `" + sqltableJob.getMysqlSchema() + "`.`" + sqltableJob.getMysqlTable() + "` SET `active`=0";
                    stntMySQL2.executeUpdate(inactiveQuery);
                    final ResultSet rs2 = stntMySQL2.executeQuery(sqltableJob.getSQLSelectQuery());
                    int counter = 0;
                    while (rs2.next()) {
                        counter++;
                        final String mysqlSetClause = sqltableJob.getMysqlSetClause(rs2);
                        insertQuery = "INSERT INTO `" + sqltableJob.getMysqlSchema() + "`.`" + sqltableJob.getMysqlTable() + "` SET " +
                                mysqlSetClause +
                                " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " +
                                mysqlSetClause;
                        stntMySQL2.executeUpdate(insertQuery);
                        if (counter % 5000 == 0) {
                            System.out.println("Processed " + counter + " rows.");
                        }
                    }
                    rs2.close();

                    if (!sqltableJob.isKeepInactives()) {
                        final String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM `" + sqltableJob.getMysqlSchema() + "`.`" + sqltableJob.getMysqlTable() + "`" +
                                "WHERE `active`=0";
                        stntMySQL2.executeUpdate(deleteQuery);
                    }

                    stntMySQL2.execute("COMMIT");//last line of try block
                    System.out.println("Committed " + sqltableJob.getMysqlTable() + " transaction");
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Transaction level exception thrown.");
                    System.out.println(insertQuery);
                    stntMySQL2.execute("ROLLBACK");
                    System.out.println("MySQL query rolled back.");
                }
            //Another MySQL Transaction goes here
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Connection level exception thrown.");
            } finally {
                if (stntMySQL2 != null) {
                    try {
                        stntMySQL2.close();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }
                }
                if (connMySQL2 != null) {
                    try {
                        connMySQL2.close();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Program level exception thrown.");
        }
    }
```

SQLTableJob is

```
package equipmentinventoryimporter;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
/**
 *
 * @author jmgreen
 */
public interface SQLTableJob {

    public String getMysqlSchema();

    public String getMysqlTable();

    public String getSQLSelectQuery();

    public String getMysqlSetClause(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException;

    public boolean isKeepInactives();
}
```

and the specific SQLTableJob being referenced is

```
public class SQLTableJob10I implements SQLTableJob{

public boolean isKeepInactives() {
        return true;
    }

    public String getMysqlSchema() {
        return "Temp_Equipment_Inventory";
    }

    public String getMysqlTable() {
        return "PC_Combined";
    }

    public String getSQLSelectQuery() {
        final String sqlSelectQuery = "SELECT *" +
                " FROM Temp_Equipment_Inventory.PC_Table10i";
        return sqlSelectQuery;
    }

    public String getMysqlSetClause(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        final String mysqlSetClause =
                "`Account_No`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("Account_No")) +
                ",`Inventory_No`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("Inventory_No")) +
                ",`Building_No`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("Building_No")) +
                ",`Location`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("Location")) +
                ",`FYYR_No`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("FYYR_No")) +
                ",`Cost`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("Cost")) +
                ",`Name`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("Name")) +
                ",`Desc1`= ''" +
                ",`Desc2`= ''" +
                ",`Desc3`= ''" +
                ",`CDCATY`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("CDCATY")) +
                ",`CDSRCE`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("CDSRCE")) +
                ",`FLDCAL`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("FLDCAL")) +
                ",`CDACQN`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("CDACQN")) +
                ",`FLOWNR`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("FLOWNR")) +
                ",`FLSHAR`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("FLSHAR")) +
                ",`CDDELT`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("CDDELT")) +
                ",`CNYTDT`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("CNYTDT")) +
                ",`NOPURO`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("NOPURO")) +
                ",`NOPIMO`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("NOPIMO")) +
                ",`CDPREI`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("CDPREI")) +
                ",`Original_Amount`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("Original_Amount")) +
                ",`Serial_Code`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("Serial_Code")) +
                ",`CDCOMP`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("CDCOMP")) +
                ",`NOCHECK`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("NOCHECK")) +
                ",`CDCOMM`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("CDCOMM")) +
                ",`Last_Update`=" + Importer.sqlDate(rs.getString("Last_Update")) +
                ",`CDDEPT`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("CDDEPT")) +
                ",`Room_No`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("Room_No")) +
                ",`Date_Scanned`=" + Importer.sqlDate(rs.getString("Date_Scanned")) +
                ",`Date_Acquired`=" + Importer.sqlDate(rs.getString("Date_Acquired")) +
                ",`Manufacturer_Name`=" + Importer.sqlChar(rs.getString("Manufacturer_Name")) +
                ",`Expiry_Date`=" + Importer.sqlDate(rs.getString("Expiry_Date")) +
                ",`Active`='1'";
        return mysqlSetClause;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide content of file SQLTableJob.java?

Comment: check original post for the requested edits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

> A `ResultSet` object is automatically closed when the `Statement` object that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

From your code:

```
                stntMySQL2.executeUpdate(inactiveQuery);
                final ResultSet rs2 = stntMySQL2.executeQuery(sqltableJob.getSQLSelectQuery());
                while (rs2.next()) {
                    ...
                    stntMySQL2.executeUpdate(insertQuery);
```

You are re-executing `stntMySQL2` inside the loop. This automatically closes `rs2`.

To fix, use a different statement object inside the loop.

Comment: Also note that closing a `Connection` will automatically close all `Statement` instances that were created from it. This isn't in the JavaDoc, but the JDBC spec mandates it. Found that out recently via another question.